# How to edit multiple variables inside a structure in C

Tags: c, structure, coding-efficiency

```
typedef struct
{
   string color;
   int age;
}Dog;


int main(void)
{
    Dog cookie = ("brown", 6);
    cookie.color = "blue";
    cookie.age = 12;
}
```

Hello, I'd like to know if there's a way to edit multiple structure values as such,
while only using a single line instead of repeating "structName.varName" over and over.

Would there be a similar method for changing multiple values for objects in C as well? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please note that `("brown", 6)` is a syntax error.

Comment: You *are* allowed to write two assignments on a single line, if that is the only requirement. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign multiple struct members a value at once, by using a *compound literal* temporary object:

```
cookie = (Dog) { "blue", 12 };
```

Or for increased readability, combine this with *designated initializers* (equivalent code):

```
cookie = (Dog) { .color = "blue", .age = 12 };
```

Comment: However, this will assign *all* struct members, not a strict subset of struct members.

Comment: @IanAbbott Not really stated as a requirement in the question. In order to preserve some members, you'd have to do something like: `cookie = (Dog) { .color = "blue", .age = 12, .fur = cookie.fur };`. I think this should be ok in terms of assignment operator sequencing.

Comment: I just thought it was worth pointing out as a caution for the uninitiated who might assume it was only assigning the named members.

Comment: If that's a common operation I'd still prefer an appropriate setter function… Otherwise biting the bullet and do two manual assignments appears preferable to me as well.